# Convert EELS map to line scan data but DM 3.0 still recognize it as a map

Tags: dm-script

I wrote a script to convert the EELS map to EELS line scan data, and it works well with DM 2.0. I can deal with it as directly collected EELS line scan data with DM2.0.  But it does not work with DM 3.0 and the above version. It looks DM 3.0 still recognizes it as an EELS map file. DM3.0 still tried to generate elemental maps with multiple windows from it not generate line scan profiles with one single window and said the display type is incorrect. Not sure what code/command I need to add to fit the DM 3.0 and above versions.  Appreciate any suggestions/comments.

```
image source

source := getFrontImage()

number sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ
source.Get3Dsize(sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ)

Result( "Original size:"+ sizeX +"; "+ sizeY+"; "+sizeZ+""+"\n" )

image sum
number regionsizeX = 1
number regionsizeY = sizeY
number row,col

Result( "new size:"+ regionsizeX +"; "+ regionsizeY+"; "+row+""+row+" "+"\n" )

sum := RealImage("Line Scan of [0,0,"+regionSizeY+","+regionSizeX+"]",4,sizeX/regionSizeX,sizey/regionsizeY,sizeZ)
//sum := ImageClone(source)

sum = 0

for (row=0;row<regionsizeY;row++) for (col=0;col<regionSizeX;col++)
{
OpenAndSetProgressWindow("Doing sub-block","x = "+col," y = "+row)
sum += Slice3(source,col,row,0,0,sizeX/regionSizeX,regionsizeX,1,sizeY/regionSizeY,regionSizeY,2,sizez,1)
}

OpenAndSetProgressWindow("","","")

ImageCopyCalibrationFrom(sum, source)

sum.setdisplaytype (1)

sum.SetStringNote( "Meta Data:Format", "Spectrum image" )
sum.SetStringNote( "Meta Data:Signal", "EELS" )

showimage(sum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also a bit confused by your terminology. When you write "Convert a Map into a LineScan" do you mean:

a) Convert a 3D Spectrum-Image (xy scan, one spectral dimension) into a 2D Line-Scan Spectrum-Image (one spatial dimension, one spectral dimension)

or

b) Convert a 2D Map (xy scan, one value) in a 1D Line-Trace (one spatial dimension, one value per point) ?

I suppose you mean a) and answer to that.

---

I'm surprised if/that your script would work without issues in GMS 2.

Your final (supposedly line-scan SI) data is still a 3D dataset with the dispersion running in Z-direction. This is *not* the typical LineScan SI data format (which is dispersion in X, spatial dimension in Y, no Z dimension).

Am I right in thinking that you want to "collapse" your 3D data along the y-dimension (by summing) ?

If so, what you want to do is:

```c
// Get Input
image src3D := GetFrontImage()
number sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ
if ( 3 != src3D.ImageGetNumDimensions() ) Throw( "Input not 3D")
src3D.Get3Dsize(sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ)

// Optional: Use Rect-ROI on image to specify area
// If no selection, will return full FOV
number t,l,b,r
src3D.GetSelection(t,l,b,r)

// Prepare output (for summing 3D of rect-selection along y)
// NB: 2D container has:
//   X dimension (spatial) along Y
//   Z dimension (energy) along X
number nSpatial  = r - l
number nSpectral = sizeZ
number eOrig, eScale, sOrig, sScale
string eUnit, sUnit
src3D.ImageGetDimensionCalibration(0, sOrig, sScale, sUnit, 0)
src3D.ImageGetDimensionCalibration(2, eOrig, eScale, eUnit, 0)

string name
if ( nSpatial != sizeX )
    name = "Y-projection of [" + t + "," + l + "," + b + "," + r + "] over " + (b-t) + " rows"
else
    name = "Y-projection over " + sizeY + " rows"

image dst2D := RealImage( name, 4, nSpectral, nSpatial )
dst2D.ImageSetDimensionCalibration(0, eOrig, eScale, eUnit, 0)
dst2D.ImageSetDimensionCalibration(1, sOrig, sScale, sUnit, 0)

// Copy Tags (contains necessary meta tags! Meta Data Format & Signal)
dst2D.ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupCopyTagsFrom( src3D.ImageGetTagGroup() )

// Display (with captions)
dst2D.ShowImage()
dst2D.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplaySetCaptionOn(1)

number doFAST = 0
if ( !doFAST )
{
    // Perform actuall summing (projection) by summing "line by line" 
    // into the LinePlot SI. Note the flipping of input and output dimensions!
    for( number y = t; y<b; y++ )
    {
        number lineNumber = y - t
        dst2D.slice2( 0,0,0, 0,nSpectral,1, 1,nSpatial,1 ) += src3D.slice2( l,y,0, 2,nSpectral,1, 0,nSpatial,1)
    }
}
else
{
    // Alternative (faster) projection. Use dedicated projection command.
    image proj := src3D[l,t,0,r,b,nSpectral].Project(1)         // Outcome of projectsion is having x=x and y=z, so need flip axis
    dst2D = proj.slice2(0,0,0, 1,nSpectral,1, 0,nSpatial,1 )    // Flip axis
}

// Display (with captions)
dst2D.ShowImage()
dst2D.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplaySetCaptionOn(1)
```

Note that iterating using slice blocks is fast, but not as fast as the dedicated 'Project' command available in latest GMS versions. The example uses either, but lines #51-56 might not be available in older GMS.

---

#### Edit to address comment below:

Other relevant meta data for spectra is also found in the tags. For EELS, in particular the collection & convergence angle as well as the HT is of importance. You can find out about the tag-path by checking the tags of a properly acquired EELS spectrum.

Or, you can find out about their tag-paths by "converting" an empty 1D line-plot into an EELS spectrum and then attempting a quantification. You will get the prompt to fill in the data. After doing so, check the tags of the image:

[image: Prompt]
[image: Info in tags]

Comment: Is there any way I can add the operation voltage (200 kV or 300 kV) information and convergent angle and collection angle (from original 3D EELS maps) to these 2D arrays? it keeps asking the information, that wastes time. Thanks

Comment: @together All meta-info is stored (and can thus be added) as tags to images, you just need to find the appropriate tag-paths. This is best done by looking at the taggroup of a properly tagged spectrum. The "Meta Data" taggroup contains the overall type information, specific info is usually found elsewhere. EELS info f.e. in the "EELS" taggroup. I post additional info as edit to my answer above in a minute...